# $\mu$-measureabilty implies $\sigma$-additivity

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation

In: L.C. Evans & R.F. Gariepy, *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions, Revised Edition*, CRC Press, Boca Raton, 2015 the following theorem is shown:
Let $\{A_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$, be a sequence of $\mu$-measurable sets, then
$$
\mu\left(\bigsqcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k\right)= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(A_k).
$$

---

This is the proof:
Write
$$
B_{j}:=\bigsqcup_{k=1}^{j} A_{k} \quad(j=1,2, \ldots) .
$$
Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mu\left(B_{j+1}\right) &=\mu\left(B_{j+1} \cap A_{j+1}\right)+\mu\left(B_{j+1}-A_{j+1}\right) \\
&=\mu\left(A_{j+1}\right)+\mu\left(B_{j}\right) \quad(j=1, \ldots)
\end{aligned}
$$
whence
$$
\mu\left(\bigsqcup_{k=1}^{j} A_{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{j} \mu\left(A_{k}\right) \quad(j=1, \ldots) .
$$
It follows that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu\left(A_{k}\right) \leq \mu\left(\bigsqcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k}\right)
$$
from which assertion the statement follows.

---

My problem: I do not understand some parts of this proof:

(i) Why does the author use
$$
\mu\left(\bigsqcup_{k=1}^{j} A_{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{j} \mu\left(A_{k}\right) \quad(j=1, \ldots) 
$$
this is finite additivity, why does this hold?

(ii) What is $\mu$ exactly? I assume an outer measure?

(iii) How does the last step follow for $\infty$? I get it for finite $j$, is it alright to just let $j\rightarrow \infty$???

Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 2):

(i) He is showing this property by induction where the argument is the line above. So he starts with $B_{j+1}$ and is showing that you can split off the $A's$ one at a time to end up with the sum of the measure of the individual $A_i's$.

(ii) Yes I assume so but this will be explained in his book somewhere like at the start of the section or chapter.

(iii) This is because you have the inclusion
$$
\bigcup_{k=1}^j A_j \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k,
$$
which gives you an inequality. After that you can take a monotone limit on the other side.

Comment: Yep, that's right.